# Open Fire as XMPP server

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, strophe

Im new to openfire, can some tell me how to use the openfire as chat server?, Ive installed it in my windows machine and got to admin panel created some users but not exactly clear how to use it exactly? I want to make an application to provide chat service from site owner to site visitors like Zopim/Olark etc.
Please advice
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use a XMPP client (pidgin for instance).
If you have to implement you chat service on a website, you should have a look at the strophe librairy : http://strophe.im/ 
with the very good book associated :
http://professionalxmpp.com/